# How to initialize value of foreign key in Django form

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Im trying to initialize a model form where both fields are foreign key.

Model:

```
class Subcohort(models.Model):
cohort_id=models.ForeignKey(Cohort,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0,db_constraint=False,related_name='subcohortid')
parent_id=models.ForeignKey(Cohort,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=0,db_constraint=False,related_name='subparentid')
```

Form:

```
class SubcohortForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Subcohort

        fields = [
            "cohort_id","parent_id",
        ]
```

Views:

```
initialvalue2={
     'cohort_id':int(cohortidnew),
     'parent_id':id,
}

     form2 = SubcohortForm(initialvalue2)
            
     if form2.is_valid():
          return redirect('/dashboard')
```

It is saying my form is not valid. Can someone explain what is the reason behind this and how to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because, you have not saved that form after validation.

let's save it:

```
 if form2.is_valid():
      form2.save()
      return redirect('/dashboard')
```

And now your problem will be solved..

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to save. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the form intialize with these values, then please pass the values using [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values) parameter when initiaiting form object:

```
initialvalue2={
     'cohort_id':int(cohortidnew),
     'parent_id':id,
}

form2 = SubcohortForm(initial = initialvalue2)
```

You can send this `form2` instance to the template directly without validating it. But you should check if the form is valid on post request. For example:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
     form2 = SubcohortForm(initial = initialvalue2)
     return render(request, template_name, context={'form2':form2})
else:
    form = SubcohortForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
       return render(request, template_name, context={'form2':form})
```